# pytables installation error in osx

Tags: python, macos, pytables, xcode5.1

My Xcode version is 5.1 so I tried to install pytables by this.

```
ARCHFLAGS=-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future sudo -E pip install tables
```

However, I still got errors

```
error: Command "cc -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -DENABLE_DTRACE -DMACOSX -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wshorten-64-to-32 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future -arch x86_64 -arch i386 -pipe -DNDEBUG=1 -DHAVE_BZ2_LIB=1 -DHAVE_LZ4=1 -DHAVE_SNAPPY=1 -DHAVE_ZLIB=1 -Ic-blosc/hdf5 -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy/core/include -I/usr/local/include -I/sw/include -I/opt/include -I/opt/local/include -I/usr/include -I/include -Ic-blosc/blosc -Ic-blosc/internal-complibs/lz4-r113 -Ic-blosc/internal-complibs/snappy-1.1.1 -Ic-blosc/internal-complibs/zlib-1.2.8 -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c tables/utilsextension.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/tables/utilsextension.o -Isrc -DH5Acreate_vers=2 -DH5Aiterate_vers=2 -DH5Dcreate_vers=2 -DH5Dopen_vers=2 -DH5Eclear_vers=2 -DH5Eprint_vers=2 -DH5Epush_vers=2 -DH5Eset_auto_vers=2 -DH5Eget_auto_vers=2 -DH5Ewalk_vers=2 -DH5E_auto_t_vers=2 -DH5Gcreate_vers=2 -DH5Gopen_vers=2 -DH5Pget_filter_vers=2 -DH5Pget_filter_by_id_vers=2 -DH5Tarray_create_vers=2 -DH5Tget_array_dims_vers=2 -DH5Z_class_t_vers=2 -DH5_NO_DEPRECATED_SYMBOLS -msse2" failed with exit status 1


Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools; __file__='/Users/hchung/Downloads/build/tables/setup.py'; execfile('/Users/hchung/Downloads/build/tables/setup.py')" install --single-version-externally-managed --record /var/folders/zy/dh0v2pzd47z5qj42jm5b428w0000gn/T/pip-6zEwtv-record/install-record.txt failed with error code 1
```

Can someone help me go through this?